# Unable to assign command output in expect script

Tags: expect

I want to execute the below command in an expect script.

```
`netstat -nr | while read line;do flag=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f4); if [[ $flag == "UG" ]];then gateway=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2);echo $gateway;fi;done`
```

The aim of the script is to login to a host and get the gateway of the hots to create another ip ( eth0 ) with ifcong eth0:0 `<ip>` and add a IP route thereafter with-- `ip route add <ip> via <gateway ip>`.

i have tried the below possibilities:
1)

```
`expect -c '
   spawn bash -c "ssh user@host"
   expect {
     // password provided
          }
   expect "*?$*"
   send "\$cmd"
expect EOF
    '`
```

For this i get the error: missing )
    while executing
"set cmd "netstat -nr | while read line;do flag=$(echo $line | cut -d"
couldn't read file " -f4); if [[ $flag == "UG" ]];then gateway=$(echo $line | cut -d": no such file or directory

2)

```
`expect -c
   spawn bash -c "ssh user@host"
   expect {
     // password provided
          }
   expect "*?$*"
   send "netstat -nr | while read line;do flag=\$(echo \$line | cut -d' ' -f4); if [[ \$flag == "UG" ]];then gateway=\$(echo \$line | cut -d' ' -f2);echo \$gateway;fi;done\r"
expect EOF
   '`
```

For this i get error as: `couldn't read file " -f4); if [[ $flag == "UG" ]];then gateway=$(echo $line | cut -d": no such file or directory`

Is there no way to execute bash commands inside an expect script and register the out to a variable so that it can be used subsequently in the expect script.

I have tried out the way of `set output $expect_out(buffer)` but it does not register the output at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach {whole gw f} [regexp -all -inline {\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)} [exec netstat -nr]] {
        if {$f eq "UG"} {
                puts "Gateway : $gw"
        }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Gateway : 192.xx.xx.1
```

Comment: Adding this code snippet makes the script run but no output. see Below the script:

`expect -c '
spawn bash -c "ssh user@$env(hostname)"
sleep 15
expect {//password provided }
expect "*?]$*"
send "su\r"
expect "*?ssword:*"
send "pass\r"
expect "*?]#*"
send "cd /opt/\r"
expect "*?]#*"
send "pwd\r"
expect "*?]#*"
foreach {whole gw f} [regexp -all -inline {\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)} 
exec netstat -nr]] {
if {$f == "UG"} {
puts "Gateway : $gw"
}
}
expect "*?]#*"
send "echo \$gw\r"
expect EOF '`

It give proper o/p for `pwd` and then shows `echo $gw`. blank output for 'gw'